# Why `cirq` needs `Qid` class instead of just `Qudit` class?

Tags: programming, cirq, quantum-state

I am just wondering in what way `cirq.Qid` class generalizes qudits. From `cirq.Qid` documentation we read that it

> Identifies a quantum object such as a qubit, qudit, resonator, etc.

I am not sure what this resonator means and if it is somehow connected to other qudits in the system.

Could anyone clarify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, originally the idea was that we didn't want to exclude things like continuous quantum systems, and ancillary systems being used as control surfaces, and concepts like "a place where an ion might be" as opposed to the ion itself. So we went with a very generic "identifier for quantum-associated thing" name (qid).

At some point Qid gained a `dimension` method that returns an integer telling you how many quantum levels there are... so it really basically is a qudit now.